# Change dates to 1st of each month

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In Excel, how can I change dates to the first of each month in a column of various dates?

For example, the date `12/13/14` needs to be converted to `12/01/14`. Only the 1st of each month must appear in the column.

Comment: @pnuts: What's your point? What the OP want to do is trivial for a even a novice Excel user. Read the docs. No programming here.

Comment: @pnuts: That was answered before SU even existed...

Comment: @pnuts: Well that is just my single opinion. I also dont agree that  shell scripting should be on SO. If there is consensus, democracy wins.

Answer (score 3):

Please try :

```
=EOMONTH(A1,-1)+1
```

[EOMONTH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/eomonth-HP005209076.aspx):

> Returns the serial number for the last day of the month that is the indicated number of months before or after start_date. Use EOMONTH to calculate maturity dates or due dates that fall on the last day of the month.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> **EOMONTH(start_date,months)**
>
> *Start_date* is a date that represents the starting date. Dates should be entered by using the DATE function, or as results of other formulas or functions. For example, use DATE(2008,5,23) for the 23rd day of May, 2008. Problems can occur if dates are entered as text.
>
> *Months* is the number of months before or after *start_date*. A positive value for months yields a future date; a negative value yields a past date.
>
> •  If *months* is not an integer, it is truncated.

Regarding the bullet point, this means that the *start_date* may be a date/time serial number, where the time part is ignored by this function.

So in the example, if A1 is `December 13, 2014` with the second parameter (ie `-1`) the result is `November 30, 2014`. Add one (`+1`) in accordance with conventional date/time serial numbering and `December 1, 2014` should be returned.